# what is the rel attribute and why is it used in this code?

Tags: jquery

I know that the rel attribute refers to the stylesheet (correct me if I'm wrong), but I don't know why it is there in this piece of code. I'm taking this from a magic line demo http://css-tricks.com/examples/MagicLine/ (the second one).

```
$MagicLineTwo
     .data("origColor", $(".current_page_item_two a").attr("rel"));
```

the `.attr('rel')` is what I am getting confused about. What is it storing as the value of `origColor?`

Comment: From [**MDN**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a): *" rel: For anchors containing the `href` attribute, this attribute specifies the relationship of the target object to the link object. The value is a space-separated list of relationship values. The values and their semantics will be registered by some authority that might have meaning to the document author. The default relationship, if no other is given, is void. Use this attribute only if the href attribute is present."* Looks like the attribute is abused to store arbitrary data.

Comment: http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/document-metadata.html#attr-link-rel

Answer (score 1):

Once upon a time, when the world wide web was the wild wild west, developers "hijacked" the `rel` attribute to store all sorts of things on DOM elements. Since `rel` is a real attribute, it played nice with browsers—they didn't freak out when they encountered it. Now in the modern world, we can store data in `data-` attributes. This is referred to as **DOM Expando**:

> Expando Properties are attributes (of a DOM element in this case) which are not part of the standard definition.
>
> *http://wiki.greasespot.net/Expando_Properties*

Modern browsers see these attributes and say "I don't know what you are, but that's cool with me", and carry on rendering HTML.

The appropriate way to do this, is to leave `rel` out of it (as pointed out above, it has it's own purpose), and use the proper `data-` attribute (note the `data-` prefix below):

```
<div id="myCoolDiv" data-original-color="blue"></div>
```

Then, getting that value is the same as before:

```
var originalColor = $("#myCoolDiv").attr("data-original-color");
```

Answer (score 0):

It is storing the color code of where he's going to make the transition posible. Bad use of the attribute `rel` in this case. But it is possible to store data in it.